# GCC reports a stringop-overflow compile warning when using -fprofile-arcs

Tags: c++, gcc

As for GCC 10.3.0, when the following codes is compiled with the option `-fprofile-arcs`, GCC will report a `stringop-overflow` compile warning. If the option `-fprofile-arcs` is removed, then `stringop-overflow` will not occur.

```
$ g++ test.cpp -O3 -W -Wall -Werror -fprofile-arcs -o test -std=c++17 -g

In function ‘void memcpy_inlined(void*, const void*, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘EncodedUtf8Char::EncodedUtf8Char(const char*, size_t)’ at test.cpp:46:23:
test.cpp:16:29: error: writing 8 bytes into a region of size 4 [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
   16 |             __builtin_memcpy(dst + size - 8, src + size - 8, 8);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp: In constructor ‘EncodedUtf8Char::EncodedUtf8Char(const char*, size_t)’:
test.cpp:38:18: note: at offset 0 to object ‘EncodedUtf8Char::U::<unnamed struct>::bytes’ with size 4 declared here
   38 |             char bytes[4];
      |                  ^~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


__always_inline void memcpy_inlined(void *__restrict _dst, const void *__restrict _src, size_t size) {
    auto dst = static_cast<uint8_t *>(_dst);
    auto src = static_cast<const uint8_t *>(_src);

    if (size <= 16) {
        if (size >= 8) {
            __builtin_memcpy(dst + size - 8, src + size - 8, 8);
            __builtin_memcpy(dst, src, 8);
        } else if (size >= 4) {
            __builtin_memcpy(dst + size - 4, src + size - 4, 4);
            __builtin_memcpy(dst, src, 4);
        } else if (size >= 2) {
            __builtin_memcpy(dst + size - 2, src + size - 2, 2);
            __builtin_memcpy(dst, src, 2);
        } else if (size >= 1) {
            *dst = *src;
        }
    } else {
        __builtin_memcpy(dst, src, size);
    }
}


struct EncodedUtf8Char {
    static constexpr uint32_t ABSENT_ENCODED = 0xffff'ffffU;

    union U {
        struct {
            char bytes[4];
        } __attribute__((packed));
        uint32_t value;
    } u;


    explicit EncodedUtf8Char(const char *p, size_t size) {
        u.value = ABSENT_ENCODED;
        memcpy_inlined(u.bytes, p, std::min(4UL, size));
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string str = "12345678";
    EncodedUtf8Char encoded(str.data(), str.size());

    return 0;
}
```

> Add code so that program flow arcs are instrumented. During execution the program records how many times each branch and call is executed and how many times it is taken or returns.

According to the document [-fprofile-arcs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options), is it because `-fprofile-arcs` adds some codes to each branch? How to avoid this warning with `-fprofile-arcs`?

---

It seems that `const size_t& min(size_t, size_t)` with `-fprofile-arcs`, GCC cannot infer that `min(4UL, size)` is always not greater than 4.

- GCC 10.5 const size_t& min: error https://godbolt.org/z/ver8TG5bd
- GCC 10.5 size_t min: OK https://godbolt.org/z/c4GenGax4

```
// Using this function with -fprofile-arcs reports stringop-overflow.
const size_t& min(const size_t &lhs, const size_t &rhs) {
    return lhs < rhs ? lhs : rhs;
}

// Using this function with -fprofile-arcs doesn't report stringop-overflow.
size_t min(const size_t &lhs, const size_t &rhs) {
    return lhs < rhs ? lhs : rhs;
}
```

---

Besides, GCC 12 doesn't report this warning even if using `const size_t& min(size_t, size_t)`. https://godbolt.org/z/qnxG6GxTj

Comment: Some warnings happen after the code is optimized by the compiler. Those are all very fragile and give tons of false positives. They may sometimes find a true bug, but that's so rare that it isn't even worth investigating in my experience. Your options if you consider this a false positive: 1) disable this warning globally 2) disable this warning locally (pragma) 3) look closely at the intermediate representation of the code in gcc at the time the warning is printed, and tweak the code to help the compiler optimize a bit better so it realizes that the path causing the warning is unreachable.

Comment: since you have ``using namespace std;`` the ``min`` or ``max`` that the compiler uses might not be what you expect. It might be ``std::min`` or ``std::max``. This can lead to weird errors.